# How to find out if IE11 loaded a resource from cache

Tags: internet-explorer, browser-cache, developer-tools

With Chrome devtools I can check if cache was used to load a resource in the network tab. If it was used it says `<from cache>`. I see nothing similar in IE11 developer tools.

How do I figure out if cache was used to load a given resource?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like cached resources show up as greyed out 304's in the network capture when "always reload from server" is turned off.

Also, I would first check if expiration headers are set on the resource.  IE "SHOULD" respect those.  You can also test this by setting the expiration as immediate and seeing if network traffic has occurred to reload the resource.